# How to build a multi-site cloud infrastructure on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I need to create this infrastructure on AWS. I know how to construct a single batch farm, but I don't know how to create/connect several. Could you please suggest me any references/tutorials?

[image]

Comment: For something like that I suggest you do at least the AWS certified solution architect associate qualification so you understand the platform.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I finally understood what I needed. I just needed to put each batch farm in a VPC.

Comment: I guess it depends on you aims. Do you have each "batch farm" in a single subnet of a VPC, or across multiple AZs of a VPC for higher availability? Do you need multi-region for very high availability? Do you connect them using transit gateway? Do you have one batch farm spanning regions? Depends what you're trying to achieve, and what a "batch farm" is. AWS Batch is one product that may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your use case is. They look like the copies of the same infrastructure...

If you separate staging environments, then I'd suggest multiple accounts.
E.g. dev, testing, staging, production...
Each account would then have its own group of AWS resources, rightsized to their needs. E.g. a dev account typically doesn't need extra-large instances

Or would you like to have dedicated sites/groups (?) per customer, i.e. multi-tenant setup?

Comment: I was referring to different "physical" sites, so different geographical places using same AWS account. I suppose I should connect them via WAN but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Do you want them in different Availability Zones, which are within a region and logically connected but with the data centers around 50km apart? Or do you want them more like US East Coast and US West Coast? Both are possible in AWS, depends what you goals are, connectivity required, etc.

Comment: Are there specific reasons why you would want to separate them geographically, only to have them "talk to each other" anyway?
I'm thinking of data transfer costs.
If you can give us further details about your use case, we can hopefully help you more.
E.g. is it a monolithic web-server application running on an EC2 instance using RDS Aurora...?